# How does that kind of function work?

Tags: c++

I found some strange looking function (hope I'm calling it right) and can't really understand its meaning.
Maybe You can help me and tell what does it actually mean and how to use that?

```
int (*foo(const unsigned i))(const int, const int)
{
   ... // code
   return some_function;
}
```

It looks like a function pointer but the pointers I've seen, have been more like these:

```
void foo(int x, double (*pf)(int)); // function using function pointer as a parameter

double (*pf)(int); // function pointer declaration
```

Thank You for Your time.

Comment: [cdel.org](https://cdecl.org/?q=int+%28*foo%28const+unsigned%29%29%28const+int%2C+const+int%29) is a godsend for stuff like this.

Comment: Wow @WhozCraig, didn't know about that site. Looks awesome. I see it also works for C++

Comment: equivalent to: `using F = int(const int, const int);  F *foo(const unsigned i);`

Answer (score 4):

It's defining a function named `foo` that *returns* a function pointer.

`foo` takes a `const unsigned int` parameter named `i` and returns a pointer to a function that takes two `const int`s and returns an `int`.

Answer (score 1):

This

```
int (*foo(const unsigned i))(const int, const int);
```

is a declaration of function with name `foo`  that returns pointer to a function with the type `int(const int, const int)` and has one parameter of the type `const unsigned int`.

Take into account that you may remove the const qualifiers. That is these two declarations

```
int (*foo(const unsigned i))(const int, const int);
```

and

```
int (*foo(unsigned i))(int, int);
```

declare the same one function.

You could use a typedef name to simplify the declaration.

Here is a demonstrative program

```
#include <iostream>

int (*foo(const unsigned i))(const int, const int);

int bar( int x, int y )
{
    return x + y;
}

int baz( int x, int y )
{
    return x * y;
}

int main() 
{
    std::cout << foo( 0 )( 10, 20 ) << std::endl;
    std::cout << foo( 1 )( 10, 20 ) << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

typedef int ( *fp )( int, int );

fp foo( unsigned i )
{
    return i ? baz : bar;
}
```

Its output is

```
30
200
```

Instead of the typedef declaration

```
typedef int ( *fp )( int, int );
```

or

```
typedef int ( *fp )( const int, const int );
```

you may also use the alias declaration

```
using fp = int ( * )( int, int );
```

or

```
using fp = int ( * )( const int, const int );
```

or even

```
using fp = int ( * )( const int, int );
```

and

```
using fp = int ( * )( int, const int );
```